# playing music through links

Tags: javascript

everyone, i have some question, is there a way that a link of music can be played on a particular player on a webpage?

Comment: Far too vague, please add more specific detail.

Comment: are you trying to ask how to stream a media file from a server into your webpage?

Answer (score 1):

You can't control how the browser plays any kind of media - that's under the control of the user and the browser - and you have no idea if any particular software's installed. At best you can do is embed the media file and hope that the client's got a player that can handle the file and/or mime-type.

For instance, you couldn't do (making up a horribly ugly tag):

```
<embed media="mytune.mp3" playwith="winamp" />
```

You can't tell if the user's got winamp installed. At most you could do something like

```
<embed media="mytune.mp3" mimetype="audio/mpeg" />
```

and hope they've got something which can play that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to force playing through QuickTime player:

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" WIDTH="64" HEIGHT="16">
        <PARAM NAME="src" VALUE="FILE PATH HERE" >
        <PARAM NAME="autoplay" VALUE="true" >
        <EMBED PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
        SRC="FILE PATH HERE" TYPE="image/x-quicktime"
        WIDTH="64" HEIGHT="16" QTSRC="FILE PATH HERE"
        AUTOPLAY="true" > 
        </EMBED>
    </OBJECT>
```

Comment: my concern is...instead of storing music in database i only want to link the music video and play it on my own web page.

Comment: Well then you just need to embed it using `<embed>` what are you trying to play?

Comment: yap!... i already have that one but how about the file path?..my codes goes this <script type="text/javascript">
  player("container").setup({
  autostart: false,
  controlbar: "true",
  file: "video.mp4",
  duration: 1000,
  flashplayer: "js/player.swf",
  volume: 80,
  height: 250,
  width: 400
  });
  </script>   i want this for the file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckAAuuO1psg" instead of file:"video.mp4".. how can i play it to my player any idea?

Comment: You can get a youtube downloader - download the mp4 file, rename as whatever you want then upload to your server, and then point your script where it says video.mp4 to the file.

Comment: is there other way, aside from downloading the file..just linking it to other website and playing it to my player?

Comment: Well you COULD do it but it isn't advisable due to the fact the URL may change/It may be against the site's TOS etc, uploading to your own hosting is defiantly the best method.

Comment: oh!!... okay!..your right it really against in TOS and other policy but in a case of URL change there is other way to solve, and i already solve it...thanks for your time, idea and advices..

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML5 audio tag to embed links to audio sources. It will be played with the browser's default controls. Alternatively, you could create a custom audio player using JavaScript, and still use the audio tag.

```
<audio src="http://fidelak.free.fr/reprises/The%20Doors%20-%20People%20are%20Strange.mp3" controls>
</audio>
```